# Import CSV file and append to an array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a csv file that is formatted as follows:

```
Image Id,URL,Latitude,Longitude
17609472165,https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7780/17609472165_c44d9b5a0e_q.jpg,48.843226,2.31805
11375512374,https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5494/11375512374_66a4d9af6c_q.jpg,48.844166,2.376
24768920940,https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1571/24768920940_634cc06f43_q.jpg,48.844619,2.395897
9411072065,https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7368/9411072065_5e2083a32e_q.jpg,48.844666,2.3725
9996916356,https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2807/9996916356_640c493020_q.jpg,48.844666,2.3725
24281266199,https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1623/24281266199_bf63e25c23_q.jpg,48.844925,2.389616
```

I want to import this file and for each line in the file append a point lat and lon to a 2D array. I have tried code such as the following and it is not working(or printing anything) and is giving error "ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly"

```
import numpy

data  = open('dataset_import_noaddress', 'r')
A = []

for line in data:
    fields = line.strip().split(',')
    lat = fields[2]
    lon = fields[3]
    print lat
    print lon
    newrow = [lat, lon]
    A = numpy.vstack([A, newrow])
```

Can anyone suggest why this isn't working or even better suggest a better way to achieve the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want just read your csv into a Matrix with each row latitude, longitude. So basically read, it an delete the first 2 columns

**Code**

```
import numpy as np

input = np.genfromtxt(open("dataset.csv","rb"),delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
A = np.delete(input, [0,1], 1)

print(A)
```

It just reads the csv all non float values are converted to nan. Then just remove the first 2 columns with np.delete

**Output**

```
[[ 48.843226   2.31805 ]
 [ 48.844166   2.376   ]
 [ 48.844619   2.395897]
 [ 48.844666   2.3725  ]
 [ 48.844666   2.3725  ]
 [ 48.844925   2.389616]]
```

Comment: `genfromtxt` takes a `usecols` parameter; with `usecols=[2,3]` you don't need to delete anything.

Answer (score 3):

First, you generally want to use a `with open(filename, 'r') as ...:` format. One reason for this is that the file will be automatically closed should you encounter an error.

One often uses [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) for reading csv files in Python (although you can also read the table using pd.read_csv(...) if you are using Pandas).  You then need to iterate over the reader using `for line in reader:`.

You are getting single variables and creating intermediate lists, using numpy.vstack for each row.  It would be more efficient to aggregate everything as a list and then call vstack on the whole list.

`A.append(line[2:4])` takes the third and fourth items from the list on the given row (e.g. [48.843226, 2.31805]) and appends it to the larger list A.  You should first ensure the line has at least four values before appending, keeping track of the bad lines.

Once A has been built, you then call vstack.

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    A = []
    bad_lines = []
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        if len(line) == 4:
            A.append(line[2:4])
        else:
            bad_lines.append(line)
    A = np.vstack(A)
```

Comment: You are answering OP's question... If you had given some explainations, it could be a decent answer deserving an upvote. Currently, it is a code only one, that I'm tempted to downvote :-(

Answer (score 1):

So, basically you want the lat and long data from the csv file, is that right? I would suggest you'll use `pandas'` `read_csv()`, this way there is no need to loop the file line by line. Pandas can handle all the columns all at once.

```
import pandas as pd

file_ = pd.read_csv("dataset_import_noaddress", sep = ',')
A = np.array(file_[["Latitude", "Longitude"]])
print A
```

`array([[ 48.843226,   2.31805 ],
       [ 48.844166,   2.376   ],
       [ 48.844619,   2.395897],
       [ 48.844666,   2.3725  ],
       [ 48.844666,   2.3725  ],
       [ 48.844925,   2.389616]])`